# How can I make PhpSpreadsheet function properly inside a function in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) inside a custom WordPress theme.

Let's say that my theme is named "twentytwenty".

I installed PhpSpreadsheet inside twentytwenty/phpspreadsheet, and I added this line in my functions.php to load PhpSpreadsheet.

```
require __DIR__ . '/phpspreadsheet/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then, I tried to create a test Spreadsheet, just to find out if it is working or not, so I pasted this very simple piece of code inside my functions.php, too.

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

// Create Spreadsheet
$spreadsheet     = new Spreadsheet();
$activeWorksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$activeWorksheet->setCellValue( 'A1', 'Hello World!' );

// Redirect output to client browser
header( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Report.xls"' );
header( 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' );
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter( $spreadsheet, 'Xls' );
$writer->save( 'php://output' );
```

Then, when I visit my Homepage (or any other page), a "Report.xls" file is immediately downloaded on my browser, and it has the "Hello World" text on the "A1" cell, exactly as I wanted it to be. So, the Spreadsheet is generated as expected.

But I don't want it to be downloaded on every page load, I want it to be downloaded only when I submit a specific form.

How could I implement this?

Comment: The code in your sample after your //Redirect... comment downloads the spreadsheet. You need to put it in an [action handler](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) for your form's submit button. You didn't tell us anything about your forms so it's hard to give more specific advice.